# Python ctypes crashes python when passed structure is deleted

Tags: python, windows, dll, ctypes

Python 2.7.8, Windows 7, Phyton USB programmer's DLL

After successfully calling an API function inside a DLL, and that call responding appropriately for the parameters passed (passed in a single structure).  When the structure object is deleted, or certain (but not all) contained attributes are accessed, the python interpreter crashes.

**Update:**
  It turns out, that the API documentation was stale, and did not match the include file.  Once I updated the structure following the include file, the issue was resolved.

**Update 2:**
I am having trouble dealing with a mutable array that needs to be passed. It is the "Data".  I have tried many iterations, and I cannot find an example with a mutable in a structure.

```
MaxMemorySize = 1024
MemoryBuffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer("Hello", MaxMemorySize)

class Memory_Params(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ =  [("Size", ctypes.wintypes.UINT),
                 ("BufferNumber", ctypes.wintypes.UINT),
                 ("LayerNumber", ctypes.wintypes.UINT),
                 ("AddressLow", ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
                 ("AddressHigh", ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
                 ("Data", ctypes.c_char_p ),
                 ("DataSize", ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
                 ("FillValue", ctypes.wintypes.DWORD)
                ]
WriteLayer = ctypes.windll.ACI.ACI_ReadLayer
WriteLayer.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(Memory_Params)]
WriteLayer.restype = ctypes.HRESULT

WData = Memory_Params(ctypes.sizeof(Memory_Params),0,0,0,0,MemoryBuffer,15,0)

print 'write result', WriteLayer(WData)
```

Creating the Memory_Params object is where it usually throws an error.  Although when I change the type to a fixed string, then the object is created, but the API call returns a 1 which means:
define ACI_ERR_INVALID_PARAMS_SIZE     1  // Invalid structure size in ACI function

Comment: Did you verify the definition of `ACI_Launch_Params`? In the version I just downloaded, ACIProg.h defines this struct with 3 additional out parameters: `('NumSites', wintypes.UINT),` `('ConnectionId', wintypes.LPVOID),` `('ProgrammerName', ctypes.c_char * 64)`.

Comment: Also the returned status codes aren't compatible with a COM `HRESULT` (i.e. a negative value indicates an error). The `ACI_ERR_*` values range from 0 to 14. If you want to check the result automatically, use `Launch.errcheck`. Read the docs for using [`errcheck`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._FuncPtr.errcheck).

Comment: After following the include file, instead of the documentation, everything seems to be working perfect.  Thank you for your help, especially the length you went to research my issue.

Comment: See Update 2:  Now I am stuck with trying to send a mutable memory block to the API.  I cannot find an example, and everything I have tried has failed.  Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2):

The lesson learned is this:  If you are experiencing erratic behavior with a ctypes interface, even if the API function seems to be completing as expected.  Double check that your arguments are correct.